# How do I dynamically size HTMLAREA objects in PeopleTools 8.50?

Tags: peoplesoft

The organization I work for is upgrading from PeopleTools 8.47 to PeopleTools 8.50.  We have run into a problem with HTMLAREAs.

In 8.47, you were able to make a HTMLAREA on a page with as small a height as you wanted – saving page real estate within the application designer.  Any text input into the area would expand the area at run time without problems (for all non-Safari browsers anyway).  This is not the case in PeopleTools 8.50 as far as we can determine.  Text put into an HTMLAREA will overflow the area if the area does not have enough height.  This text will then overlay the text etc, below.

Has anyone run into this problem and found a fix?  Pages were displaying with a similar problem in Safari 3.x under PeopleTools 8.47.

Thanks in advance,

Nicholas Rule

Answer (score 1):

What you describe should be due to some stylesheet aloowing overlapping

Here's a list of what I suggest you should check :
- What's the default stylesheet applied to your page ?
- Is there any embedded stylesheet in the HTMLAREA value ?
- IF not, could you explore the stylesheet of the page to try to find at which level this overflow is allow ? (I use webdeveloper  Firefox plugin for such purposes)

Hope it give you some clues about your issue :)

See ya 
Telk